# redis4cats Scala redis.set not setting any records

Tags: scala, redis, scala-cats

**Scala redis4cats library**

```
redis: RedisCommands[IO, String, String]
```

- Below code line in scala does not set any records in redis.

`redis.set("a", "x")`

- Although when setting via terminal works

`127.0.0.1:6379[2]> set a b  OK`

- And retrieving that record which was set from terminal from scala works as well which verifies the redis connection from Scala is set properly.

Comment: Can you give more code context? What is `spinResultsRedis`? What does `set` returns?

Comment: I am going to assume `set` is returning a value of type `IO[Unit]` which you are then discarding; which, of course, would mean nothing will be done.

Comment: spinResultsRedis is the redis instance defined as below

`spinResultsRedis: RedisCommands[IO, String, String]`

and set returns nothing since its a `IO[Unit]`

Comment: Just changed it to `redis` to avoid future confusions.

Comment: Do you know how `IO` work? Put very simply, they are lazy and do nothing until you "run" them (directly or combined to another one). If you don't use Cats yet, you should probably not use this library but directly a Redis library like Lettuce. Or take the time to learn a bit about Cats IO :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by confusion about the api of `IO`

Your code, `redis.set("a", "x")` returns a value of type `IO[Unit]`

A value of type `IO` is a *plan* of a computation that will be executed later. It is "referentially transparent", meaning that it's the same as a value like `1 + 1`

This means that for example, these two programs are semantically *equivalent*:

```
IO.println("hi") >> IO.println("hi")

val hi = IO.println("hi")
hi >> hi
```

Contrast with using non-IO:

```
println("hi"); println("hi")

val hi = println("hi")
hi; hi
```

Those two programs are *not* equivalent - println is not referentially transparent.

This has the implication that **if you do not use the `IO` value, it is equivalent to never constructing it**.

That is to say, **methods `foo` and `bar` are equivalent**:

```
def foo = {
  redis.set("a", "x")
  123
}
def bar = {
  123
}
```

The best way to handle your case is to make sure the `redis.set` program you've constructed is incorporated into a `flatMap` from a higher-up section of code, for example,

```
// NB: fa >> fb === fa.flatMap(_ => fb)
def setA: IO[Unit] = redis.set("a", "x") >> IO.println("'a' has been set")
```

If the rest of your codebase is not using `IO`, you can instead use one of the "`unsafe`" methods to immediately execute the program described by your `IO` value. In this case, the name "unsafe" refers to the fact that referential integrity is no longer preserved, meaning that you can't apply equational reasoning to the code.

```
// Import the default IORuntime to execute your `IO` program
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits._
def doStuff: Unit = {
  redis.set("a", "x").unsafeRunSync()
  println("done"
}

def doStuffAsync: Future[Unit] =
  redis.set("a", "x").unsafeToFuture()
```

I recommend reading the ["Programs as values"](http://systemfw.org/archive.html) post series from one of the authors of cats-effect and fs2, it goes into more detail about why the library is structured this way and what abilities become enabled from using it.